# weird screen resolution in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, dell, resolution

I have Dell 7520 with AMD Raedon 7XXXM graphics card, thankfully, I got to make it work. But the problem now is screen resolution, as I have screen resolution of 1920 X 1080 for 15.6" laptop, which is way too much. In the Display Monitor settings, I cannot change it to whatever I want, only the resolution with 16:9 works perfectly. I have options for other resolution setting but, selecting others brings the screen edges near, that means it leaves gap on both sides of screens. And to read contents from such high resolution is too small, as I need magnifying glass.

I have other suitable 16:9 resolution as 1360 X 768 but thats too big. I want something like 1600 X 1024 which would be good resolution for me. But when I change that via Display Monitor settings, again the edge becomes narrow.

I don't have the option of widening the layout from keyboard shortcuts too, if there is any way to fix this then it'd be very great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add undetected resolutions.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. In the terminal run

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
    1366x768       60.0*+   50.0  
    1360x768       59.8     60.0  
    1024x768       60.0  
    800x600        60.3     56.2  
    640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Note *LVDS1* in the output. That's the mode in this case; yours might be different. I'll refer to it as `<mode>`.

Now create modeline for your resolution. You want 16:9 -> 1366x768 at 60Hz. Run

```
cvt 1366 768 60
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

I'll refer to everything after the word "Modeline" as `<modeline>`

Now create the new mode with the modeline from the previous command. Run

```
xrandr --newmode <modeline>
```

Now add the mode (see `xrandr` command above). Run

```
xrandr --addmode <mode> 1366x768
```

Finally switch to it. Run

```
sudo xrandr --output <mode> --mode 1366x768
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed info... it works, but somewhat weird graphics... I'll try to fix it, if I can.